# Generation of Unique ID

Tags: r

Can some help with how to generate a unique 6 digit URN in R,as I don't know how to do this please.
Below are the rule for the URN

1. It needs to be alphanumeric,start with letter and maybe end with   letter (e.g AA34YB)
2. Use only upper case alphabets
3. Do not use the alphabets O or I (this is the alphabet after H and before J)
4. Use only    digits from 1- 9. Exclude 0
5. First  two digit should be letter,then followed by 2 digit number and end with 2 digit letter,e.g "AA22DD","EE34TY","ER67YU"
6. All records must contain number as shown in rule 5
7. IT MUST BE 6 DIGIT PLEASE

I would love to generate upto 4 million unique records please.Any R code suggestion is highly welcome.I am not an expert in R,actually new to R

Thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

You can use `expand.grid` to *generate Unique ID's*.

```
n <- 10
t1 <- LETTERS[!LETTERS %in% c("O", "I")]
t2 <- 1:9
#t1 <- rawToChar(as.raw(c(65:72,74:78,80:90)), multiple = TRUE) #Alternativ
#t2 <- rawToChar(as.raw(49:57), multiple = TRUE)
apply(expand.grid(t1, t1, t2, t2, t1, t1)[seq(n),], 1, paste, collapse = "")
#       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8 
#"AA11AA" "BA11AA" "CA11AA" "DA11AA" "EA11AA" "FA11AA" "GA11AA" "HA11AA" 
#       9       10 
#"JA11AA" "KA11AA"

set.seed(1) #Sample randomly
apply(expand.grid(t1, t1, t2, t2, t1, t1)[sample(length(t1)^4*length(t2)^2, n),]
  , 1, paste, collapse = "")
#10938497 17633234 12201267 18120554 21612295 21509711 13901861  6841049 
#"SL15UK" "BG59TR" "CU65XL" "BH54ES" "GJ13HV" "YF31FV" "EE79KN" "SV66CG" 
#23945701 10770210 
#"NK23KX" "TG68QK"
```

In case it needs to **much memory** look [@Joseph-Crispell's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59264819/10488504) answer.

Comment: Thanks @GKI, I have tried with 1000 observations,it works fine.Will try with 2-3 million records.And update you

Answer (score 2):

here is a function that will generate ordered unique IDs:

```
generateIDs <- function(n, existing=NULL){

  # Initialise a counter to produce IDs
  counter <- 0

  # Create a arrays of letters and digits
  letters <- LETTERS[LETTERS %in% c("O", "I") == FALSE]
  digits <- 1:9

  # Initialise an array to store the IDs created
  ids <- c()

  # iterate through the letters
  for(first in letters){

    # iterate through the letters
    for(second in letters){

      # iterate through the digits
      for(third in digits){

        # iterate through the digits
        for(fourth in digits){

          # iterate through the letters
          for(fifth in letters){

            # iterate through the letters
            for(sixth in letters){

              # Create the unique code
              code <- paste0(first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth)

              # Check if already exists
              if(code %in% existing == FALSE){

                # Iterate the counter
                counter <- counter + 1

                # Store the ID
                ids[counter] <- code
                existing[length(existing) + 1] <- code

                # Check if created enough IDs
                if(counter == n){
                  return(ids)
                }

                # Note progress
                if(counter %% 10000 == 0){
                  cat("\rCreated", counter, "ids!")
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That is a horrific number of nested for loops but it avoids the inefficient random generation of IDs. You can test it using the following code:

```
generateIDs(10)

"AA11AA" "AA11AB" "AA11AC" "AA11AD" "AA11AE" "AA11AF" "AA11AG" "AA11AH" "AA11AJ" "AA11AK"
```

Note that ideally you should run this function once. Theoretically, this function could create up to `26873856` unique IDs **but it doesn't scale well!**

See @GKi's answer for a much better solution! :-)

Comment: Thanks @Joseph-Crispell's ,will try your method.Much appreciated